# How I retain IP of a remote PC to connect using windows remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control

I have a computer which has dynamic IP meaning its IP change over time but I want to access this computer using windows desktop connection so how I can retain the IP so I can use it to connect to this PC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution is to use Teamviewer unattended installation. It is free and I can remote control the PC no matter the public IP changes

Comment: Teamviewer isn't free and monitors your use. It stops working if it thinks you are using it for non-personal or commercial use.

Comment: I am using it for personal use so it is free !!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean your public IP changes (you're a DSL/ADSL customer) then the only solutions you have:

1. See if your ISP can offer you a static public IP - you may be charged extra for this.
2. Use a dynamic DNS service such as DynDNS where you install a small application on your PC and it keeps DynDNS's systems updated with your remote computer's public IP and you point your Remote Desktop Client at the DyNDNS address (usually a URL such as bighchris.dyndns.com) which will automatically resolve to the ever changing public IP of your remote computer's public IP. Note: there are free and paid-for dynamic DNS services. The free ones are good but you have to do various things such as actually use the URL at least once a month or renew the account once a month to keep it active.

Answer (score 1):

Remote in, and sign up with dyn.com for a dynamic dns account. They don't cost much, and they check via an app you install on the machine if the IP address changes and update it to whatever address you have chosen, for example test.dyndns.org = your.ip.add.ress - The software you need to install is called dyn updater.

Don't bother with free dyndns services as these require you have to sign in every 30 days to make it work month by month.

you then type in test.dyndns.org instead of your IP address and that will keep track of the IP changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that your public-IP is changing. In this case you can use a free Dynamic DNS provider to associate the IP  with a name.

You can do with this provider it is free http://www.noip.com/

Just it has these limits:

- 3 Hostnames
- Limited Domains
- Confirm every 30 days

Here you have a guide http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/getting-started-with-no-ip-com/

If the problem is that your computer has dynamic IP in your LAN why yo do this?

Just you can use the hostname. The DNS will resolve the name with the IP.

Comment: Yes I mean public IP, is there another free DNS I can use that does not require confirmation ?

Comment: In order to keep your free DNS you need to confirm in their webpage every month .

Answer (score 1):

Unless you talk with your ISP to give you static IP, you can't. But you can have a permanent hostname. I recommend duckdns.org - as they seem best till now, and they don't require much confirmation/etc.
Login to your Google or Facebook account
Access www.duckdns.org
Make an account by using "Sign in with Google" or "Login with Facebook".
Then, add a subdomain, like "welliam.duckdns.org" and click Add domain.
Then click Install, click windows gui, install the duckdns.org client, do all that.
Then, you'll have updated IP on your permanent hostname, every time your PC is on, updated by the installed client.
Then, you can have access to your PC using this new permanent hostname (like welliam.duckdns.org or what you choose).
Don't forget to port forward if you need that!!...

best luck,
Eng. Andrei Caba